# Clarity container element to wrap clr-datagrid element

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there any Clarity element to wrap the container of clr-datagrid element in html? Please suggest me the solution to wrap the clr-datagrid using clarity element.
In the below instead of "**div**" element, i want to use clarity element. So that clrDgLoading will work. Here now it is not working as div is not known to clrDgLoading.

```
<div [clrDgLoading]="loading">
   <clr-datagrid *ngIf="some condition which i need">
       ....................
   </clr-datagrid>
</div>
```

I want loader to work first and then i will add my condition to clr-datagrid whether to show/hide the table or not(depends on the data presence).

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking here. Applications can wrap the datagrid in a container as they see fit to and it will expand to fill the space inside the container. Can you clarify this a bit with some code that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have updated my queries with example.

Comment: It sounds like the app will need to write logic and use an `*ngIf` on the datagrid container. `clrDgLoading` is used for server driven datagrids with pagination and the user is paging through the items. This  approach (ngIf) will allow the app to control when the datagrid is shown and hidden irrespective of the loading state.

Comment: The problem here is i am not able to add ClgDgLoading to div. Div is not known to clrDgLoading. It is looking for clarity element instead of div.

Comment: clrDgLoading is an input on ClrDatagrid it goes there by design. To code shown needs to reverse the ngIf on the datagrid with clrDgLoading so that you fetch your data and do your conditional check and then set the wrapper five to true when the app is ready. You may not need clrDgLoading on the datagrid. It’s hard to say without seeing a working app though. If you have more questions please create a stackblitz that had a minimum reproduction of what you are trying to do, fetch data, check conditions and render a datagrid from one of the Clarity starters here: http://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a spinner like the [angular material spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview) or the [ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner) for progress before loading the datagrid.

Example material spinner:

```
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

Example ngx-spinner:

```
<ngx-spinner
bdOpacity = 0.9bdColor = "#333"size = "medium"color = "#fff"type = "line-spin-clockwise-fade"[fullScreen] = "false"
>
<p style="color: white" > Loading... </p>
```

[DEMO ngx-spinner](https://napster2210.github.io/ngx-spinner/)